# Querying an XML document using Linq-to-XML

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML Schema:

```
<Root>
   <EventSet>
      <Event>
         <id> 
            //random id 
         </id>
         <time>
            <localTime> 
               //random local time 
            </localtime>
            <utcTime> 
               //corresponding UTC time 
            </utcTime>
         </time>
      </Event>
   </EventSet>
</Root>
```

Given an `XDocument` (called `xDoc` in this case), I can get the root by: `var root = xDoc.Root;`

I tried `var events = xDoc.Descendants("EventSet").Descendants("Event");` to query all events within an `EventSet`, but it returned `null`. *I'm pretty sure that's not right.*

How would I query events, then iterate through to get each event's `id`, `localTime`, and `utcTime`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem. Having fixed the XML so that the tags match up, this works:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
{    
    public static void Main()
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load("Test.xml");
        var query = doc.Descendants("EventSet")
                       .Descendants("Event");
        Console.WriteLine(query.Count()); // 1
    }    
}
```

Or to get the bits:

```
foreach (var element in query)
{
    string id = (string) element.Element("id");
    string localTime = (string) element.Element("time").Element("localTime");
    string utcTime = (string) element.Element("time").Element("utcTime");
    ...
}
```

It's possible that you could cast to `DateTime` instead of `string` - it depends on the format within your element.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do a query like this one

```
var events = from e in xDoc.Root.Desendants("Event") select new {
id = e.Element("id").Value
Time = e.Element("time").Element("localTime").Value ////or you can cast it into datetime
UtcTime = e.Elelemt("time").Element("utcTime").Value //or you can cast it into datetime
}
```